# GAE: Queues, Quotas and backend instances

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-quotas

I have a queue with a lot of tasks in it. I would like to use one backend instance to process this queue. My quota info tells me I have blown my budget on hundreds of frontend instance hours and have not used any backend instance hours. As I had configured only one backend instance, I was expecting to be charged no more than 1 (backend) instance hour per hour. Here is my configuration:

backends.yaml

```
backends:
- name: worker
  class: B8
  instances: 1
  options:dynamic
```

queue.yaml

```
- name: import
  rate: 20/s
  bucket_size: 40
```

adding tasks to queue in my script

```
deferred.defer(importFunction, _target='worker', _queue="import")
```

bill status

```
Resource                     Usage   
Frontend Instance Hours      198.70 Instance Hours      
Backend Instance Hours       0.00 Instance Hours
```

Task Headers

```
X-AppEngine-Current-Namespace   
Content-Type    application/octet-stream
Referer http://worker.appname.appspot.com/_ah/queue/deferred
Content-Length  1619
Host    worker.appname.appspot.com
User-Agent  AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)
```

Comment: have you deployed the backend code?

Comment: ah no - I didn't realise you had to do that. I'm assuming the instructions are in here somewhere: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/ ?

Comment: exactly these: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#Commands

Answer (score 0):

I needed to deploy my backend code:

```
appcfg.py backends update dir instance_name
```